# Sections, Projections, and Polars of $\ell_p$ Balls

Tags: lp-spaces, convex-geometry

Let $A\in\mathbb R^{n\times d}$ where $n \geq d$. Let $1\leq p < \infty$ and let $q$ be its Hölder conjugate exponent. Is it true that
$$
\{x\in\mathbb R^d : \|Ax\|_p \leq 1\}^\circ = A^\top(B_q^n)
$$
? Here, $\circ$ denotes the polar and $B_p^n\subseteq\mathbb R^n$ is the unit $\ell_p$ ball.

It is known that the polar of the polytope $\{x\in\mathbb R^d : \|Ax\|_\infty \leq 1\}$ is given by the convex hull of $\pm$ the rows of $A$, i.e. $\{A^\top y : y\in\mathbb R^n, \|y\|_1\leq 1\} = A^\top(B_1^n)$ (see, e.g., Lemma 1.3 in these [notes](https://sites.math.washington.edu/%7Erothvoss/lecturenotes/AsymptoticConvexGeometry-13-OCT-2021.pdf) by Rothvoss). It is also simple to check that the polar of the ellipsoid $\{x\in\mathbb R^d : \|Ax\|_2 \leq 1\}$ is given by the ellipsoid $\{A^\top y : y\in\mathbb R^n, \|y\|_2\leq 1\} = A^\top(B_2^n)$.

The proof for the cases of $p\in\{1,2\}$ seem to rely on specific properties of those spaces, and I have found them difficult to generalize. It is easy to check one inclusion by Hölder's inequality; if $z = A^\top y$ for some $\|y\|_q \leq 1$, then for every $x$ with $\|Ax\|_p\leq 1$, $$\langle x,A^\top y\rangle = \langle Ax,y\rangle \leq \|Ax\|_p \|y\|_q \leq 1.$$

I have also poked around in the following papers, but they do not seem to give the result I am looking for as far as I can tell:

*Meyer, Mathieu; Pajor, Alain*, [**Sections of the unit ball of $\ell ^ n_ p$**](http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/0022-1236(88)90068-7), J. Funct. Anal. 80, No. 1, 109-123 (1988). [ZBL0667.46004](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0667.46004).

*Barthe, Franck; Naor, Assaf*, [**Hyperplane projections of the unit ball of $\ell_{p}^{n}$**](http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/s00454-001-0066-3), Discrete Comput. Geom. 27, No. 2, 215-226 (2002). [ZBL0999.52003](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0999.52003).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By the polarity theorem, it suffices to verify that
$$
(A^\top(B_q^n))^\circ = \{x\in\mathbb R^d : \|Ax\|_p \leq 1\}.
$$
This is significantly easier to verify. Indeed, if $x$ has $\|Ax\|_p \leq 1$, then Hölder's inequality implies that for all $\|y\|_q \leq 1$,
$$
\langle x,A^\top y\rangle = \langle Ax,y\rangle \leq \|Ax\|_p\|y\|_q \leq 1
$$
so $\{x\in\mathbb R^d : \|Ax\|_p \leq 1\}\subseteq (A^\top(B_q^n))^\circ$, and if $x$ satisfies
$$
\langle x,A^\top y\rangle = \langle Ax,y\rangle \leq 1
$$
for all $\|y\|_q\leq 1$, then it is in particular true for $y$ which witnesses the tightness of Hölder's inequality for $Ax$, so $\langle Ax,y\rangle = \|Ax\|_p \leq 1$.